# Failing to use the FlagsAttribute on an enum (Cannot resolve symbol 'HasFlag')

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, flags, bitflags

I have an asmx web service in c# and have recently discovered the very useful `FlagsAttribute` for enums. My declaration is as follows:

```
[Flags] 
public enum eAdPriority
{
    None = 0,
    Gold = 1,
    Silver = 2,
    Homepage = 4
}
```

I then test the enum as follows:

```
eAdPriority test = eAdPriority.Gold | eAdPriority.Homepage | eAdPriority.Silver;
test.HasFlag(eAdPriority.Gold);
```

However, the `HasFlag` part of the last line is highlighted red **Cannot resolve symbol 'HasFlag'** and my code wont compile. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure you're using at least .NET 4.0?

Comment: What is eClassifiedAdPriority ? I tried using var val = test.HasFlag(eAdPriority.Gold); and getting true ;

Comment: @RAJ: Typo, corrected - thanks.

Comment: @Fratyx: <embarrassed> - that was my problem, what n00b, sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enum.HasFlag` is only availible in .NET Framework 4.0 or above. If you are using .NET Framework 3.5, you could include extension method from [this article](http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2011/08/enum-hasflag-method-extension-for-4-0-framework/) to mimic the HasFlag functionality. For the sake of completness, here is the code (credit goes to the author of the article):

```
    public static bool HasFlag(this Enum variable, Enum value)
    {
        // check if from the same type.
        if (variable.GetType() != value.GetType())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The checked flag is not from the same type as the checked variable.");
        }

        Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        ulong num = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        ulong num2 = Convert.ToUInt64(variable);

        return (num2 & num) == num;
    }
```